# Como aumentar exponencialmente a velocidade da mudança de valor de uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero aumentar exponencialmente a velocidade da mudança do valor de uma variável. Eu tentei fazer isso, mas não deu certo. Ao tentar fazer isso, utilizei 2 setInterval, mas não funcionou. No código abaixo eu tentei aumentar a velocidade na mudança do valor da variável x, mas não deu muito certo. Gostaria que me ajudasse e também gostaria de saber como faço para aumentar exponencialmente a velocidade de mudança do valor da variável x.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="vel"></p>
    <script>

      var x = 100;
      var y = 1000;
      document.getElementById("vel").innerHTML = x;

      var exponencial = setInterval(function() {
         y -= 2*pow(2, 4);
      }, 1000);

      var time = setInterval(function() {
         x += 1;
         document.getElementById("vel").innerHTML = x;
      }, y);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que você deseja isso. Mas não use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout`. Começando com 1 segundo (1000 milissegundos) vai decrementando o tempo em 10 milissegundos (você pode ajustar).

Crie uma função que é chamada a cada tempo, com o valor do tempo diminuído em 10 milissegundos, aumentando a velocidade.

Execute o código abaixo e veja que em alguns instantes a velocidade vai aumentando:

```js
function tempo(y){
   y -= 10;
   var time = setTimeout(function() {
      x++;
      document.getElementById("vel").innerHTML = x;
      tempo(y);
   }, y);
}

var x = 100;
var y = 1000;
document.getElementById("vel").innerHTML = x;
tempo(y);
```

```html
<p id="vel"></p>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que o método `pow` que ele esta chamando está errado, o correto é `Math.pow()`.